# C++ CLI Visual Studio desktop application path

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, c++-cli, desktop-application

I'm trying to add a PDF file to my application.
I open it with the full path from the  C: file, but it is not open if I change my project's location.

How can I use local path related to the project folder?

I'm using this code for the full path:

```
String^ Path1 = "regle/GuideCODE_FIXER.pdf";
axAcroPDF1->src = Path1;
```

Some advice, say use resource folder?

Comment: Have you tried putting .pdf file in same folder as output exe (of your program)

Comment: if you make the path "./regle/GuideCODE_FIXER.pdf" it will be relative to the path where the executable is started from (usually your project dir). You can navigate with "../../regle.."

Comment: this is haw should be the relative path

Comment: String^ Path = "C:/Users/danger iheb/Desktop/pfe 2018/1  my work/1 project progress/Projet1/Projet1/regle/GuideCODE_FIXER.pdf";
AdRead->src = Path;

Comment: this is the full path

Comment: Can you open the file when the path doesn't contain spaces? if so, use quated file path.

Comment: Always use full path names, c:\foo\bar\file.ext.  Use Assembly::GetEntryAssembly.Location to get the full path to your EXE file, Path::GetDirectoryName() to get its folder, Path::Combine() to create the full path to the file you want.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: char* path_reg = "regle/regle_type.txt";    
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open(path_reg, ifstream::in | ifstream::out);

Comment: this exeple of ifstream can open a file text from project folder with local path in tha same folder (regle

Comment: i wanna do the same with the pdf file but doesnt work